# How to copy code, and automatically copy all of that code's dependencies, to another project

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

I have searched for this answer for days. I work in a large organization and often I find that I am duplicating bits of functionality that already exists in some other service/project somewhere. What I currently have to do is copy some method over to our project, and then tediously go through and try to find all of the relevant code and dependencies that that method depends on to copy them over as well. Is there any plugin, for any IDE, that lets you copy a method from one project to another, including all and any code and files that that method depends on? What would such a tool even be called?

Comment: You can try to do Refactor | [Move](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/move-refactorings.html) action, but you need for both project be under the same IDE project (add other project [as a module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html) to existing project)

Comment: Yep. That's it!